# isn't right to prove that $\sqrt{2}$/4 is irrational number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

Assume $\sqrt{2}$/4 is rational number.

rational number have p/q in the lowest term.

\begin{align}\sqrt{2}/4 = p/q\\
\sqrt{2}=4p/q\\ 
2=16p^2/q^2\\
2q^2=16p^2\\
2q^2=2(8p^2) \\ 
q^2=2(4p^2)\\
\end{align}

Then we know that q is even number according to if $q^2$ is even then $q$ is even.

Also,we have $2q^2$=$16p^2$ in the above,we know that $16p^2$ is a even number.

So we can construct the form in the below:
\begin{align}2(16a)=16p^2\\p^2=2a
\end{align}

Then we know that p is even number according to if $p^2$ is even then $p$ is even.

Since we  assumed that $\sqrt{2}$/4 is in the lowest form of rational number,but the result showed p and q have the common factor 2.It causes to contradiction  and means that our assumption is wrong.

Therefore,$\sqrt{2}$/4 is irrational number.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a question here? Your proof is not the most succinct, but seems correct.

Comment: I just want to verify my proof so that i can continue to do other proof that rely on the result of this proof,thanks.

Comment: oh my mistake sorry sir

Comment: Your question title says $\frac{\sqrt{4}}{2}$. Your quiestion body says $\frac{\sqrt2}{4}$. Which is it?

Comment: I correct it,sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ If $\frac {\sqrt 2} {4}$ is a rational number then so is $\sqrt 2 = \frac 1 2 \times \frac {4} {\sqrt 2}.$ Is $\sqrt 2$ a rational number?

Answer (score 6):

Seems fine.

Alternatively, suppose that $\frac{\sqrt2}4$ is rational number, $q$. Then $\sqrt{2}=4q$ is a rational number, which contradicts that $\sqrt2$ is irrational.